Attempt to resize button in TKinter returning error
Making an extremely simple program where a button follows the mouse, and when clicked, should randomly resize. But I when I run the code below, I get an error, saying that the "height" property is unknown.
Code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random

window = tk.Tk()

def moved(e):
    myx = e.x
    myy = e.y
    mylbl.place(x=myx - 20, y=myy - 20)

def randomsize():
    size = random.randrange(20, 200)
    sizey = size * 2
    mylbl.config(width= sizey, height = size)

mylbl = ttk.Button(window, text="Hello", command=randomsize, height=30, width = 60)
mylbl.place(x=10, y=10)
window.bind("<Motion>", moved)

window.mainloop()

Error:
in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"


Ttk widgets aren't generally configured by keyword options passed to their constructor or .configure() method, you have to use Ttk Style objects.  The simplest fix would be to use an ordinary tk.Button widget here, rather than the ttk version.

In ttk, I think configuring height and width directly is not possible.(But in tkinter.Button, It is possible).
So, to configure new height in ttk, we should change the font size and padding. This should be done using ttk.Style method.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random    

# An empty dict is declared as I want to avoid some global variables
dct ={}

def moved(e):
    
    # As e.x and e.y are optional global variables, I've declared them as values of dct
    dct['myx'] = e.x
    dct['myy'] = e.y
    
    # Remove the originally placed position
    dct['mylbl'].place_forget()
    
    # Place in new position
    dct['mylbl'].place(x= dct['myx'] - 20, y= dct['myy'] - 20)

def randomsize():

    # As the button's height changes with font size and padding, we get random values for font_size and padding
    x_pad = random.randrange(5, 40)
    y_pad = x_pad * 2
    fnt_size = random.randrange(8, 25)
    
    # If previous font_size & new font_size are same, create another font_size
    fnt_size = random.randrange(8, 25) if fnt_size == fnt_size else fnt_size
    
    # Hide the previousely placed position
    dct['mylbl'].place_forget()
    
    # Configure new style to the button with new font size and padding
    dct['stl'].configure('TButton', font = ('Helvetica', fnt_size), padding = (x_pad, y_pad))
    
    # Apply the new style
    dct['mylbl'] = ttk.Button(window, text="Hello", command=randomsize, style = 'TButton')
    
    # I haven't changed the position. But If you want to place the button to the moved position, change x = dct['myx'] and y = dct['myy']
    dct['mylbl'].place(x=10, y=10)

window = tk.Tk()

# Add geometry
window.geometry('400x300')

# To avoid using global variable, Style is made as a value of the dict
dct['stl'] = ttk.Style()
dct['stl'].configure('TLabel', font=('Helvetica', 12), padding=5)   


# To avoid using global variable, Button is made as a value of the dict
dct['mylbl'] = ttk.Button(window, text="Hello", command=randomsize, style = 'TButton')
dct['mylbl'].place(x=10, y=10)

window.bind("<Motion>", moved)

window.mainloop()

